# vb 2010 checkbox loop

Tags: vb.net, string, checkbox

So I'm trying to get this permission app going. I'm stuck in that I want to have the string adkey be the name of the checkbox as in "cbo" & adkey. so that the same string will the name of the check box. I got kinda mad and copied the whole thing here so its kind of a mess.

```
Dim ADkey As String() =
        {"NoChangingWallpaper", "NoHTMlWallpaper"}
    ' Dim cbo As String = 
    Dim cho As CheckBox
    cho = CType("cbo" & ADkey), CheckBox)
    Dim readvalue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop", ADkey, Nothing)
    'MsgBox("The value is " & CStr(readValue))
    ' Dim cho(ADkey) As CheckBox
    cho.Name = ADkey
    If readvalue = "1" Then
        cho.Checked = True
    Else
        cho.Checked = False
    End If
```

the msgbox portion was for testing

Comment: LOL@ `I got kind of mad and copied the whole thing here so its kind of a mess`

Comment: You know you're trying to use an array as if it's one string, right?

Comment: I had figured that but I wasn't sure how to link different strings. All the examples i have come across are with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add all your checkboxes to a `Dictionary(Of String, Checkbox)` object:

```
Dim ADkey As String() =
    {"NoChangingWallpaper", "NoHTMlWallpaper"}

'This code can move to where the checkboxes are first created, as long as you can reach the variable from here
Dim checkboxes As New Dictionary(Of String, Checkbox) From 
  {
     {"NoChangingWallpaper", cboNoChangingWallpaper},
     {"NoHTMlWallpaper", cboNoHTMLWallpaper}
  }

For Each key As String in ADKey.Where(Function(k) checkboxes.ContainsKey(k))
    Dim regvalue As Boolean = (My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop", key, Nothing)="1")
    Dim box As Checkbox = checkboxes(key)
    box.Name = key
    box.Checked = regvalue
Next Key
```

And as I look at this, to avoid keeping double records of the keys I might cut out the string array entirely and do it like this:

```
'This code can move to where the checkboxes are first created, as long as you can reach the variable from here
Dim checkboxes As New Dictionary(Of String, Checkbox) From 
  {
     {"NoChangingWallpaper", cboNoChangingWallpaper},
     {"NoHTMlWallpaper", cboNoHTMLWallpaper}
  }

For Each key As String in checkboxes.Keys
    Dim regvalue As Boolean = (My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop", key, Nothing)="1")
    Dim box As Checkbox = checkboxes(key)
    box.Name = key
    box.Checked = regvalue
Next Key
```

Whether or not you want this version depends on whether you're always looking at all the boxes, or whether you might something only want to update certain ones.

Comment: This completely works. Thanks so much, you have made my day :).